# ASP.NET error with component one

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an error when I try to use the component one library. The problem is if I install the library and when I try to use one of their components, I show this error

> Error 1 Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly
>   'C1.Win.BarCode.4, Version=4.0.20163.226, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79882d576c6336da' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>   App_WebReferences/ShortUrlApi/

The problem is that I am not using anything about barcode, and if I search in all the project for this word, I can't find any reference about that. It's weird because if I create a new project and I add this component, everything works fine. I copy the same web.config and all the bin of the old project and everything works fine. So I don't know where the error is.

Thanks a million

Comment: Could it be that you are using a package which is depending on that assembly?

Comment: No, because in the empty project everything works fine without this assembly. The problem is that I can't find where is this line written

Comment: Does the C1.Win.BarCode.4 library exist in the bin\Debug folder in both the old & new project?

Comment: No, is not in the bin folder (I don't have the debug folder in any of them)

Comment: sounds like this ComponentOne library depends on the barcode library. I assume their product is closed-source, so you won't be able to see where the dependency is written, necessarily. Check you've installed everything correctly and followed their documentation. Since it appears to be a paid product, you can probably contact them for support as well.

Comment: And why everything works fine in a new project with the same bin folder and same web.config @ADyson ?

Comment: maybe it installed the component properly in the new project? Maybe something is corrupt in the old one? If you really can't find any other reference to it in the old project, that seems like the most likely. Have you tried "Clean Solution" and "Rebuild" on the old one, to clear it out?

Comment: Yes... But it's weird because the component one is installed in the visual studio and when you use one component, automatically add the reference in the bin folder and in the web.config